# VB how do I call a 'Public Sub' from a Class in the main form? (OOP)

Tags: vb.net

I need to know how to call a Public Sub into the main form when I click a button. I need to show the calculations which are done in the class in the main form within a listbox.

Comment: Can you share some code that you are working on?

Comment: I will add the add code

Comment: how do I add the code, sorry I'm new here..

Comment: Dont worry i found it

Answer (score 3):

You simply type the name of your sub. Here is a simple example :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Here you "call" the sub.
    ' If you have parameters you put them in the brackets.
    YourSub()

End Sub

Public Sub YourSub() ' You can add parameters.
    ' Some code.
End Sub
```